# Can every list comprehension be duplicated in a normal if statement

Tags: python, list-comprehension, lazy-evaluation

I was wondering if list comprehensions have any special evaluation order that makes them impossible to replicate in a normal if statement:

For example, is it possible to write the same thing without a list comprehension?  If so, is it possible without using "else"?

```
a, b = set(), set()
[a.add(i) for i in range(5) if i % 2 == 0 or b.add(i)]
```

Specifically, I am demonstrating the lazy evaluation of "or" in this case, but I cannot figure out how to demonstrate this outside of a list comprehension because, when using 'if' in a normal for loop, the set.add() is the thing being evaluated in a boolean context instead of the actual expression `( i % 2 == 0 )`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. The if-statement work as any other if-statement and isn't different whether it's in a list comprehension or not.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Ok, please write me some code using a normal for loop and if statement that will result in the sets looking the same as they do when this list comprehension is run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list comprehension is the same as:

```
for i in range(5):
    if i % 2 == 0 or b.add(i):
        a.add(i)
```

So the if-statement isn't any different than in the list comprehension.

Your code can be replaced by:

```
for i in range(5):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        a.add(i)
    else:
        b.add(i)
```

I would consider your previous example ambiguous from a reading standpoint. Since `b.add(i)` is done in-place, it'll always return `None` (which is interpreted as `False`), so it does nothing for the condition. The second code snippet is much more readable, as it's clear what your intent is.

Comment: Thanks, it seems so simple now.

Comment: Would this be considered stylistically bad?  it seems like this abuses or to circumvent an else statement, and that it is better to strictly use and/or or if/else when possible. Mixing them like this seems less readable.

Comment: @GL2014 I added my view to your question in the answer.

Comment: So basically, I would consider it bad, not because of you're mixing and/or with if/else, but because you're using the short-circuiting behaviour of `or` to do actual work, instead of deciding whether to branch. I'd say it's better to use the statement in an if to just be used for branching. Of course, there are always exceptions to the rule, but I would not consider this example to be one.